# Files won't load to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, upload

[image: Upload status showing green ticks]

I am uploading files to Google Drive. One PDF and one MS Word document won't load correctly. I have tried multiple times (both drag and drop and right click to upload), and they show up in my Google Drive folder as files with 0 bytes. The files on my hard drive look fine if I open them on my computer, and the other PDFs and Word docs in the folder (some uploaded today) look fine.

[image: File size details]

Comment: pdf is 827kb, word doc is 247kb. Previously uploaded files which were larger uploaded fine. I just tried rebooting the computer to upload files again. Status report shows green checkmarks.

Comment: 30MB of 15GB used

Comment: Tried re-booting my modem just now also. I've also added some screenshots.

Comment: I've put the files on a flash drive and walked it over to my Macbook, and they loaded fine. Tried another file from my desktop Windows 8 machine, and I still am getting empty files uploaded. I would like it to work on both machines.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm also working on Windows 8. And after many attempts with some troublesome PDF files, I solved in a cumbersome way.
First, I sent the files to myself via mail using the web application. Once I got my own message I selected the attached files and click the option that says, send to google drive. Voila!. 
Not the best solution, but at least a solution that doesn't involve changing machines.